# TensorFlow: how to batch mut-mul a batch tensor by a weight variable?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following batch shape:

```
 [?,227,227]
```

And the following weight variable:

```
 weight_tensor = tf.truncated_normal([227,227],**{'stddev':0.1,'mean':0.0})

 weight_var = tf.Variable(weight_tensor)
```

But when I do `tf.batch_matmul`:

```
 matrix = tf.batch_matmul(prev_net_2d,weight_var)
```

I fail with the following error:

> ValueError: Shapes (?,) and () must have the same rank

---

So my question becomes: How do I do this?

How do I just have a weight_variable in 2D that gets multiplied by each individual picture (227x227) so that I have a (227x227) output??  The flat version of this operation completely exhausts the resources...plus the gradient won't change the weights correctly in the flat form...

---

Alternatively: how do I split the incoming tensor along the batch dimension (?,) so that I can run the `tf.matmul` function on each of the split tensors with my weight_variable?

Comment: Ever find a solution to this?

Comment: I need solution for this as well..care to share?

Comment: @User104 I may have figured this out.  Was going to pull up my old code this weekend...but I haven't the foggiest at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could tile weights along the first dimension

```
weight_tensor = tf.truncated_normal([227,227],**{'stddev':0.1,'mean':0.0})
weight_var = tf.Variable(weight_tensor)
weight_var_batch = tf.tile(tf.expand_dims(weight_var, axis=0), [batch_size, 1, 1])
matrix = tf.matmul(prev_net_2d,weight_var_batch)
```

Although batch_matmul doesn't exist anymore

Comment: It would be nice to explain the calls to tf.expand_dims and tf.tile. Anyway thanks for the answer, +1 :)